# Which country is the slang "moola" used?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, slang

There is a slang for **money** called **moola**. Where do they commonly use it? 
I have rarely heard American or British people using this word. And in which situations could we use it?

Comment: Have you [looked it up](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slang_terms_for_money)?

Comment: Can't speak for other countries, but I can't say that article paints a very accurate picture of US slang. I've only heard a few of those terms used seriously, the rest (including moola) almost always being tongue-in-cheek, when they're used at all.

Comment: You see the spellings moola or moolah in US (and then UK) 1920s & 1930s dialogue in e.g. crime novels, or tongue-in-cheek by Bertie Wooster types.

Comment: [There is **a slang word for x** OR There is slang for x. Please correct your question. Thanks.]

Answer (score 1):

In the UK, we would use the phrase "moola(h)" when talking sarcastically or enthusiastically about money.

For example, if I was talking to my friends about a new job that I just applied for and was reasonably high payed, I could state that *"I'm gonna start bringing in the moolah"*.